# He had to have his appendix out. (parts of speech of 'out')

Tags: parts-of-speech

> He had to have his appendix out.

In the example sentence, what is the parts of speech of 'out'?

As you know, 'out' can be adv., adj., prep., and verbs of both intransitive and transitive.

'have something X' (where X is bare verb, past participle or present participle) is a widely used expression.

Comment: It's shorthand for _taken out_, if that helps.

Comment: @KateBunting Do you think it's possible to use 'have out sth' instead of 'have sth out': He had to have out his appendix ?

Comment: Traditionally "out" was analysed as an adverb, but in modern grammar it's best analysed as a preposition that indicates movement. [link](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/out)

Comment: @BillJ What do you think is the point in time to tell 'traditionally' from 'modern'? And preposition requires its 'object' but here there is no 'object'.

Comment: I was convinced about twenty years ago when I first read CGEL. But why does it matter to you?

Comment: @BillJ Did you mean "A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language" by Quirk et al., published in 1985 ?

Comment: No: Huddleston & Pullum's CGEL (2002)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'Out' is of course an adverb of direction - but in this particular context it is an idiomatic shortening of the phrasal verb *to take [something] out*.

> He had his appendix *taken out*.

Further, the entire idiom of "have [something] out" is a common way of saying something was surgically removed:

- He had a tooth out (a tooth extraction)
- He had his appendix out (an appendectomy)

Comment: Do you think it's possible to use 'have out sth' instead of 'have sth out': He had to have out his appendix ?

Comment: @BEBYGONES No, that would not make sense. The surgeon may "take out" an appendix, but the patient "had it taken out".

Comment: What if the patient himself is a surgeon doing the operation himself?

Comment: @BEBYGONES Then he has the highest pain threshold known to man. And both would be true. He had it out, and he took it out.

Comment: @BEBYGONES If you consider _had out x_ to be acceptable English, then maybe _out_ is the particle of a phrasal verb. I don't consider it acceptable nor do I think most other natives would, so `out` is still a verb to us.

Comment: Unfortunately it's very contextual.  Replace "tooth" or "appendix" with certain other parts of the anatomy normally covered by clothes, and it has a different meaning.  Or for a more innocent example, "He had his tongue out" does not imply any kind of surgery.

Comment: Mostly unrelated, but [at least one person has performed a self-appendectomy](https://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-32481442).

Comment: @theonlygusti you think "so out is still a verb"? I think it's it's an adverb because if you consider 'take sth out', here 'out' is an adverb. The verb is 'take'.

Comment: @JeffHardy the man who operated his appendix in your link is amazing with a capital A.

Comment: @BEBYGONES _out_ is  definitely not an adverb in _take sth out_, it is a particle. It is also not an adverb in your original sentence, it is syntactically a verb. I posted an answer to explain this

Answer (score -2):

> He had to have his appendix out.

*out*  is short for *taken out*, so its part-of-speech is **verb**, not adverb.

*had to* is an auxiliary modal verb expressing deontic necessity.

*have* is not an auxiliary verb as it often is (e.g. in *I have eaten*, *have* is an auxiliary verb forming the past perfect). In your sentence, *have* is the main verb and has this dictionary meaning:

> have
> 2. **experience or suffer the specified action happening or being done to (something).**
> "she had her bag stolen"

(Oxford Languages)

The action that is being done to *his appendix* is... *taken out*, shortened to *out* in your sentence.

*take out* is a phrasal verb. In *take out*, *out* is a particle because it can go either after *take*'s direct object (*take it out*) or in-between the verb and its direct object (*take out the gun*). Being able to put a noun in-between a verb and a preposition while the verb phrase retains the same meaning proves that you are dealing with a phrasal verb, rather than a verb with a prepositional phrase argument (e.g. *stand on the truck* but not **stand the truck on*).

Comment: Sorry but this is incorrect and misleading. 'Out' *can* be a particle, but not in this case. Particles can sometimes be disregarded. You couldn't say someone had their appendix taken. Taken where? You need an adverb of direction because you can take something *in*, and you can also take something *out*. For example, I took in your answer, and then I took out the trash.

Comment: @Astralbee You are wrong. It is precisely because the particle cannot be omitted that they are phrasal verbs. E.g. _he thought it over_ vs _he thought it_, clearly very different meanings (is the second even grammatical?)

Comment: That's a very poor example of a particle. A better example is 'He ate it all *up*', which means the same as 'He ate it all', so you can often omit particles without changing the meaning. 'Up' in that context is not a directional adverb. But in the OP's example, 'out' most definitely is. The organ is coming out of their body, not being transplanted *in*.

Comment: @Astralbee _eat up_ and _eat_ also have different meanings. _eat up_ means eat all of something. Some more phrasal verbs: _he chewed me out for being late_, _he chewed me for being late_, _let's wrap it up_, _let's wrap it_, _we singled out the worst performers_, _we singled the worst performers_, _I'll come to pick you up at 7_, _I'll come to pick you at 7_, _don't bring that up_, _don't bring that_, _she turned the job down_, _she turned the job_

Comment: @Astralbee have you read e.g. [the wikipedia article on phrasal verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_phrasal_verbs)? Where are your ideas coming from?

Comment: I wouldn't go along with what you say. Particle is a general term. Particles are mainly prepositions and a few adverbs. "Out" is a preposition. "Take out" is not one verb, not a constituent, but two words: the verb "take" and the preposition "out" as its complement.

Comment: Basically, two-word verbs like 'he took out the gun' and 'he took the gun out' consist of two parts: verb + adverb. But 'he looked for sth', the 'for' is a preposition absolutely.

Comment: @BillJ you're right according to the CGEL. I'll make that the answer

Comment: @BillJ why do you think _out_ is a preposition and not an adverb?

Comment: @BEBYGONES No: in modern grammar "out" is a preposition. Also, I would avoid using the term 'two-word verb'; it's misleading. At word level "took" and "out" are separate consituents.

Comment: @theonlygusti [link](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/out).

Comment: @BillJ the link you provided us with is wrong according to the grammar that I've learned until now for over two decades. 'out' is a multi-functional part of speech.

Comment: @BEBYGONES The link is not wrong. It is compiled by professional grammarians (including me) and linguists.

Comment: @BillJ that doesn't explain why out is judged to be a preposition rather than an adverb